# nginx: Mapping location with try_files

Tags: nginx, alias

I'd like to map domain.com/mail to serve content in (absolute path in my server) /var/www/default/mail

```
server {

    ### MAIN ###

    server_name             .domain.tld;
    index                   index.php;
    root                    /var/www/domain.tld/htdocs;

    listen                  80;
    listen                  443 ssl spdy;

    charset                 utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files           $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        include             /etc/nginx/conf/*.conf;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include /etc/nginx/conf/*.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

I tried adding in the server block:

```
location /mail/ {
    alias /var/www/default/mail/;
    include /etc/nginx/conf/*.conf;
}
```

But when I visit domain.tld/mail I get a 404 error. No line in logs.
So I was looking for a `try_files` solution but I can't manage to get a snippet working.

P.S.: /mail/ location should serve php files.

Comment: What are these include directives everywhere for ? Btw try_files won't work with alias directive.

Comment: I read that each location needed to include config files because having them on location / wasn't enough to target the other locations. So what would you suggest to have a location serve files from a different path in the server?

Comment: What ? This makes no sense.

Comment: What are the other `*.conf` files' contents that are included? What kinds of PHP scripts there are exactly in the `/mail` location? Please update this info to the question.